# Check element's original value for automatic blur function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using javascript/jquery, I want to automatically change a color value to its opposite on focus for text inputs, but then return them to their original color on blur.  So far the best I've come up with is storing the value in an associative array with the ID as the key and then accessing it that way, but I don't want to have to go that route.  Are there any better options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.data()` on the element in question.  It's built for exactly what you want to do.

```
$(whatever).focus(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    item.data("origVal", xxx);
}).blur(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var originalValue = item.data("origVal");
    // do whatever you want with the original value
});
```

FYI, it might be better to just create an "active" class and use CSS to control the color:

```
$(whatever).focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Then, you define the normal color in CSS and a special color when the `active` class is present.  You can just add/remove the "active" class and let the CSS control the color.

Comment: @user2024011 - I added another option.

Comment: EDIT: I didn't realize that there was no way to do inline pseudo classes or control them via javascript, so it looks like I'm going with the .data() approach.  Thanks again!